# ¿Como adjuntar un archivo en PHPMailer directo con URL?

Tags: php, email

Hoy tengo un problema y es el siguiente,
Estoy usando ***PHPMailer*** y estoy tratando de adjuntar un archivo que esta en la siguiente ruta http://app.pimsaseguros.com/_files/_img/_holidays/040616-160454_img001.pdf y mi código es el siguiente:

```
$url = 'http://app.pimsaseguros.com/_files/_img/_holidays/040616-160454_img001.pdf';
$mail->addAttachment($url,'solicitud.pdf');
```

y si me envía el mail pero sin el archivo adjunto.

Comment: Revisa los permisos que tiene el archivo o la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo, talvez no esta permito la lectura del archivo en el servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function enviar_correo($destinatarios, $mail_asunto, $mail_contendio, $from, $from_name, $archivos_adjuntos_ruta,$archivos_adjuntos_temp){
$mail= new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$body= $mail_contendio;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the protocol to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "tu.host.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->Subject = $mail_asunto;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$destinatarios=explode(",", $destinatarios);
if(!empty($destinatarios)){
foreach($destinatarios as $un_destinatario){
$mail->AddAddress($un_destinatario); //destinatarios
}
}else{
return false;
}
if(!empty($archivos_adjuntos_ruta)){
foreach($archivos_adjuntos_ruta as $archivo){
$mail->AddAttachment($archivo); // attachment
}
}
if(!empty($archivos_adjuntos_temp)){
foreach($archivos_adjuntos_temp as $nombrearchivo=>$contenidoArchivo){
$mail->AddStringAttachment($contenidoArchivo,$nombrearch ivo,'base64');
}
}
$mail->Timeout = 20;
if($mail->Send()) {
return array(true);
}else {
return array(false,"Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);
}
}
$archivos_adjuntos_ruta=array($path1,path2);
$archivos_adjuntos_temp=array(utf8_decode($strfile PDF)=>$strContenidoPdf,utf8_decode($strNomArch)=>$ strContenidoXml);
enviar_correo(...,array(),archivos_adjuntos_temp);//los archivos estan en variables temporales
enviar_correo(...,$archivos_adjuntos_ruta,array()) ;//los archivos estan en rutas en disco
enviar_correo(...,$archivos_adjuntos_ruta,archivos _adjuntos_temp);//ambas opciones al mismo tiempo
```

Answer (score 2):

En el código de la clase PHPMailer ([fuente online en GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L2380)), puedes ver que en la definición de `addAttachment` se dice que **el fichero adjunto debe tener una ruta en el sistema de archivos** y que devuelve `false` si no se puede abrir el fichero:

> ```
> * Add an attachment from a path on the filesystem.
> * Returns false if the file could not be found or read.
> ```

Ese es el motivo por el que no te añade el fichero adjunto (pasas una URL) y falla de manera silenciosa. Realmente no es silenciosa, simplemente no revisas si falla o no, deberías añadir algo que compruebe si el resultado es falso o no:

```
if (!$mail->addAttachment($url,'solicitud.pdf')) {
    // código si el archivo no se pudo abrir o leer
}
```

---

Si el fichero que quieres adjuntar está en un servidor remoto o es una URL, entonces en lugar de usar `addAttachment` podrías usar `addStringAttachment`. En [la definición del método](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L2865) se especifica (traducción mía):

> ```
> * Añade una cadena o un binario como adjunto (no en el sistema de archivos)
> * Este método puede ser usado para adjuntar ascii o datos binarios
> * como por ejemplo un registro BLOB de una base de datos.
> ```

Una solución para adjuntar el fichero sería combinar la función [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) (que lee un fichero como string) con `addStringAttachment` (no he probado el código, puede contener fallos y sería buena que añadieses algún tipo de validación para ambas funciones):

```
$url = 'http://app.pimsaseguros.com/_files/_img/_holidays/040616-160454_img001.pdf';
$fichero = file_get_contents($url);
$mail->addStringAttachment($fichero, 'solicitud.pdf');
```