# quiero mandar un adjunto por Mailer en php

Tags: php, mysql

quiero poder enviar un adjunto por correo estoy usando phpmailer la cuestion es que al momento de adjuntarlo este me lanza NULL
como error y no me lo deja mandar a ningun lado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este seria mi codigo

```
     $message=$_POST['message'];
        $adjunto = (isset($_FILES['adjunto'])) ? $_FILES['adjunto'] : null;
    
    var_dump($adjunto);
```

y como lo estoy mandando

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();                                     
$mail->Host = 'smtp.nuestrosite.com'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  
$mail->Username = 'x';                
$mail->Password = 'x';                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                          
$mail->Port = 25;                                

/** Configurar cabeceras del mensaje **/
$mail->From = 'misdatos@correo';               
$mail->FromName = 'de tal para cual';         
$mail->Subject = 'Postulacion de vacante';         

$mail->addAddress('misdatos@correo', 'misdatos@correo');



    $mail->AddAttachment($adjunto); // attachment
```

no se porque me aparece null si mi form le puse el mismo name
que seria el siguiente

correo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7248/como-adjuntar-un-archivo-en-phpmailer-directo-con-url

Comment: Además de leer eso, no pongas partes de la funcion de envio, pon la funcion completa, que asi no vemos si te falta que poner o no.

Comment: a ok pero son como archivos word y pdf que adjuntan en una variable

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que no estas capturando correctamente el adjunto. [Subida con el método POST](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['adjunto']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = $_FILES['adjunto']['name'];
$mail->AddAttachment($tmp_name, $file_name);
```

O, lo mismo:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['adjunto']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['adjunto']['name']);
```

Comment: ya me lo recibe pero aun no lo envia--- asi recibe el var_diump
Mensaje enviado correctamentestring(46) "Razer Gold PIN Store API v1.14.0.en.es (1).pdf"

Comment: @Rmendoza `no lo envía` = ?

Comment: no ya agrege una imagen en mi pregunta

Comment: @Rmendoza Verifica que tu form esté asi: `<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: si ya lo tenia ---     <form action="correos.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
pero aun asi no incluso mi input esta         <input type="file" name="adjunto" id="adjunto" required="required"class="form-control">

Comment: @Rmendoza Sospecho que no se envía porque está en una dirección temporal, y es borrado por el colector de basura una vez se envían encabezados. Además, en su ubicación temporal carece de extensión. Debes moverlo a una ubicación, accesible, desde la que pueda ser enviado usando: [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file) y luego, puedes hacer el attachment usando su nuevo nombre y ubicación.

Comment: @Rmendoza verifica en php.ini que `upload_max_filesize = 32M` y `post_max_size = 32M`, por ejemplo. A veces estos valores están en 2MB y no sabemos si ese adjunto sobrepasa ese tamaño. Has un `var_dump($_FILES['adjunto']['tmp_name']);` a ver si se está subiendo correctamente.